# Trying to register user, ejabberd returns "401 Unauthorized"

Tags: curl, oauth, ejabberd

I want to register a user in ejabberd by using the Admin REST API. I get a "401 Unauthorized" when i try to run the following CURL command.

```
curl -v -X POST -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer c3OjG78IULjJ7O90wM3JhIRXonW9bplP" http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:5280/api/register -d '{"user": "new","host": "xxx.xxx.x.xx","password": "new"}'
```

I am not sure what I am missing.

Is there a specific scope that I need to get authorized on, to register a user?
Also, I would like to add a user to a shared_roster after registering them. Please let me know if there is a specific scope that i need to use for adding the user to the shared_roster as well.

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

EDIT:
In my ejabberd.log, this is what i see

```
2016-07-21 21:51:44.366 [info] <0.533.0>@mod_http_api:log:437 API call register [{<<"user">>,<<"newuser">>},{<<"host">>,<<"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx">>},{<<"password">>,<<"newuser">>}] from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:39527
```

But no new user is created!

EDIT:
Below is what I have in my "access" section of my ejabberd.yml file

```
access: 
  register:
    all: allow
```

BTW I am using ejabberd 16.03

Comment: From the error it looks like Bearer is not authorized to register a user. Please check your acl in config file.

Comment: I am new to ejabberd. Could you please let me know what I need to have in my acl, to be able to register a user? Thanks